# non-linear weighted least-squares with full covariance matrix

Tags: r, least-squares, non-linear-regression

I'm looking for a different answer to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161372/how-to-use-the-weights-in-the-nls-non-linear-least-squares-function-in-r)

IMHO, the weight matrix is just the inverse of the covariance of the observations, which can be correlated.

I've been using `nls` because I'm fitting non-linear models, but taking the diagonal of the covariance matrix removes tons of information.
I also know about `MASS::lm.gls` that supports a full covariance matrix for linear models (not tested myself).

Anyone could point me to a library that supports full covariance matrix in a non-linear least-squares fit?